# Optimization problem: Calculus 1

Tags: calculus, optimization

A company manufactures and sells $x$ units of a product per week. The weekly average
cost in dollars per unit is $C =\frac13 x^2 + 9x + 17 + \frac{1552}{x}$
and the selling price in dollars per unit is
$p = −\frac13 x^2 − 12x + 7370$.

Find the weekly maximum profit, the production level that will realize the
maximum profit, and the price that the company should charge for each unit.

I am getting $51$ units but the answer says it should be $43$ units. I can't seem to find my mistake.

Comment: i guess you don't want to reveal how you got 51 units?

Comment: I did R(x)- x(average cost) and then took first derivative and then quadratic formula

Answer (score 0):

i am also getting the weekly max at $x = 51.093$ units/week.

weekly cost = $x\left(\frac13 x^2 + 9x + 17 +1552 x^{-1}\right)$

weekly sale = $x(-\frac13 x^2- 12x + 7370)$

weekly profit = sale - cost = $-\frac 23x^3-21x^2+7353x-1552$

derivative of profit = $-2x^2-42x+7353 = -2(x+72.036)(x-51.036)$

by the derivative test weekly profit has a global max at $x = 51.036$

Comment: Exactly what I got. Okay thank you! The answer sheet must be wrong then.

Comment: The weekly profit is  $-\frac 23x^3-21x^2+7353x-1552$

Comment: @abel. In the weekly cost, you wrote $7$ instead of $17$.

Answer (score 0):

Doing exactly the same as abel but using $17$ as the constant term in the cost function (abel used $7$), what calculus wrote is the correct equation; for the weekly profit $$P=-\frac 23x^3-21x^2+7353x-1552$$ then the derivative $$P'=-2 x^2-42 x+7353$$ cancels for $$x_{\pm}=\frac{3}{2} \left(\pm3 \sqrt{187}-7\right)$$ The value of the positive root is $\approx 51.0366$ which is very close to abel's result and identical to your.

If the answer is $43$, there is a typo somewhere (either in the equations or in the book).

**Edit**

To explain why abel and I obtained almost the same answer, keeping everything the same except the weekly average cost in dollars per unit $$C =\frac13 x^2 + 9x + k + \frac{1552}{x} $$, the profit equation becomes $$P=-\frac 23x^3-21x^2+(7370-k)x-1552$$ the derivative $$P'=-2x^2-42x+(7370-k)$$ the positive root of which being $$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{15181-2 k}-21\right)$$ which clearly reveals the very very minor impact of constant $k$ (for $k=-100$, we should get $51.51$; for $k=0$, $51.11$ and for $k=100$, $50.70$) .